# Efficient way to find a T1 in T1[] by T2[] where T2[] is a property on T1?

Tags: c#

What is a fast way to find a product by properties like in the given example? I have a list of 3000 products, each of which has a list of 12 property objects as in the example. I need to be able to find products quickly using n number of properties.

```
public class Test
{
    public class ProductProperty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public ProductProperty() { }
        public ProductProperty(string name, string value)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public ProductProperty[] Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> models = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product() { ProductName = "Test1", Properties = new ProductProperty[] { new ProductProperty("title", "car"), new ProductProperty("length", "5") } },
            new Product() { ProductName = "Test1", Properties = new ProductProperty[] { new ProductProperty("title", "car"), new ProductProperty("length", "7") } },
            new Product() { ProductName = "Test1", Properties = new ProductProperty[] { new ProductProperty("title", "ship"), new ProductProperty("length", "9") } },
        };

        var findByProps = new ProductProperty[] { new ProductProperty("title", "car"), new ProductProperty("length", "7") };

        // var product = find Product that has title=car and length=7

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you override the Equals method inside `ProductProperty`:

```
public override bool Equals(object o) => o is ProductProperty p && p.Name == Name && p.Value== Value;
```

it's easier to compare ProductProperty  with each other (you could also implement IEquatable). (NB, the syntax above is not supported by older Visual studios, but can easily be rewritten if needed)
Once overridden, any default method can be used such as Contains:

```
var product = models.FirstOrDefault(m=> findByProps.All(m.Properties.Contains));
```

Comment: If it is only one time action `FirstOrDefault` will work. If you want to do that several times I suggest to sort your collection and use binary search.

Comment: That's interesting! Care to elaborate on "m=> findByProps.All(m.Properties.Contains)"?What is passed as a param into Contains? Each of the elements in findByProps? Is it same as to write "m=> findByProps.All(prop => m.Properties.Contains(prop))"?

Comment: Yep, it is the same, but without the extra lambda. The `Contains` method of the Properties array instance is passed directly to the `All` (extension) method, so it can be called directly by each iteration inside `All`